# Fill web form without name and ID using Python

Tags: python, forms

I searched the methods to fill a form using python and found that almost all answers suggest to use "mechanize". But to use mechanize to fill a form, I need to select the form name before filling it.

```
br = Browser()
br.select_form('f')
```

I've seen forms without any "name" or "id" field. I wonder how do I fill them. One such form could be found [here](http://keepvid.com/). The input fields in the form have names but the form itself doesn't seem to have any.

Comment: Does br.select_form(nr=0) not suits you? It selects first form within br instance.

Comment: @KidBinary: Does it? I didn't know that.

Comment: I bet it does. Also, I recall that br.forms() is iterable and contains all forms on page.

Comment: @KidBinary : That solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method to achive this is more error-prone but is simpler:

```
br = Browser()
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

Where `nr` is index number of the form on the given page. The second method includes iterating over `br.forms()`:

```
br = Browser()
forms = [form for form in br.forms()]
```

And allows to choose required form as needed.